# Expo build for iOS AppDelegate.m issue

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo, appdelegate

I am having a problem to build react native iOS app via expo. It is throwing errors in AppDelegate.m
What do you think it might be the issue?
I was trying various modifications, but nothing really helped. I am being quite desperate...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
// @generated begin react-native-google-cast-import - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-da0acf16745f87cea5bffba9c0cc3a4f5e4387ea
#if __has_include(<GoogleCast/GoogleCast.h>)
#import <GoogleCast/GoogleCast.h>
#endif
// @generated end react-native-google-cast-import

#if defined(EX_DEV_MENU_ENABLED)
@import EXDevMenu;
#endif

#if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
#include <EXDevLauncher/EXDevLauncherController.h>
#endif

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

#if defined(FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED) && __has_include(<FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>)
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// @generated begin react-native-google-cast-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-2ad935d6407dfa591d7171af9da1b03d7c763404
#if __has_include(<GoogleCast/GoogleCast.h>)
  NSString *receiverAppID = kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID;
  GCKDiscoveryCriteria *criteria = [[GCKDiscoveryCriteria alloc] initWithApplicationID:receiverAppID];
  GCKCastOptions* options = [[GCKCastOptions alloc] initWithDiscoveryCriteria:criteria];
  options.startDiscoveryAfterFirstTapOnCastButton = true;
  [GCKCastContext setSharedInstanceWithOptions:options];
#endif
// @generated end react-native-google-cast-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
  RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
 }


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#if defined(FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED) && __has_include(<FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>)
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif
  
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
#if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
  EXDevLauncherController *controller = [EXDevLauncherController sharedInstance];
  [controller startWithWindow:self.window delegate:(id<EXDevLauncherControllerDelegate>)self launchOptions:launchOptions];
#else
  [self initializeReactNativeApp:launchOptions];
#endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
 }

- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules, add them here!
  return @[];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
    #if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
  return [[EXDevLauncherController sharedInstance] sourceUrl];
  #else
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #endif
 #else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
 #endif
}

// Linking API
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  #if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
  if ([EXDevLauncherController.sharedInstance onDeepLink:url options:options]) {
    return true;
  }
  #endif
  return [super application:application openURL:url options:options] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

// Universal Links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  BOOL result = [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  return [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler] || result;
}

@end

#if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
@implementation AppDelegate (EXDevLauncherControllerDelegate)

- (void)devLauncherController:(EXDevLauncherController *)developmentClientController
    didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success
{
  developmentClientController.appBridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp:[EXDevLauncherController.sharedInstance getLaunchOptions]];
}

@end
#endif
```

I have tried a various modification of this file, but no success. If I will comment all out, the build success but it shows only blank screen on the phone...

This is the errors I am getting:

```
    ❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:15:9)

  13 | #endif
  14 | 
> 15 | #import <AppDelegate.h>
     |         ^ 'AppDelegate.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
  16 | #import <React/RCTBridge.h>
  17 | #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
  18 | #import <React/RCTRootView.h>

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:54:29)

  52 | #endif
  53 | // @generated end react-native-google-cast-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
> 54 |   RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
     |                             ^ property 'reactDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  55 |   RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  56 |   rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  57 |   UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:55:33)

  53 | // @generated end react-native-google-cast-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
  54 |   RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
> 55 |   RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
     |                                 ^ property 'reactDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  56 |   rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  57 |   UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
  58 |   rootViewController.view = rootView;

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:57:48)

  55 |   RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  56 |   rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
> 57 |   UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
     |                                                ^ property 'reactDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  58 |   rootViewController.view = rootView;
  59 |   self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  60 |   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:59:8)

  57 |   UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
  58 |   rootViewController.view = rootView;
> 59 |   self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
     |        ^ property 'window' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  60 |   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  61 | 
  62 |   return bridge;

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:60:9)

  58 |   rootViewController.view = rootView;
  59 |   self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
> 60 |   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     |         ^ property 'window' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  61 | 
  62 |   return bridge;
  63 |  }

❌  (ios/IckonicMobile/AppDelegate.m:72:8)

  70 | #endif
  71 |   
> 72 |   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
     |        ^ property 'window' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  73 |   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  74 | #if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
  75 |   EXDevLauncherController *controller = [EXDevLauncherController sharedInstance];
```

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20850
-- You could tried downgrading Expo to 47.0.9. (For me the prebuild step seems to always raise the version again...)